# SSH config - a better way? WSL & Windows Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, organizer-software

At the moment, I've got my .ssh/config file organised to have maybe 20 different hosts, however my roll is expanding to include probably another 30 or so servers with applications on.

Is there a better way to organise this? A command line application (along the lines of `pm2 monit` for example)?

Comment: (1) Define "better". What is wrong with well-maintained text file(s)? There is `Include`, you can create a separate file for each host or family of hosts. (2) "another 30 or so servers" – Do you mean "SSH servers"? i.e. 20+30 now? Or do you mean "machines that should share my `.ssh/config` and keep up with changes"? (3) I don't know `pm2`. I've skimmed through its Quick Start and I have no idea what you mean by "along the lines of `pm2 monit`" in the context of *config*. (4) Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic. The phrase "a command line application?" may lure close votes.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but not really appropriate for Super User.  The problem here is that there could be a very large number of possible solutions/answers, and all of them may be perfectly correct.  I'd recommend posting this on the WSL Reddit board ([r/bashonubuntuonwindows](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/)) where it can get the discussion it deserves.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Basically it's a nodeJS command line tool that's interactive. NodTheDroids, I'll ask on there now